# Low memory Windows CE

Tags: windows, memory, out-of-memory, windows-ce

I have Roadrover C7132P3. Windows CE.

Please help me with advice - the touchpad hangs after a couple of seconds after booting. For a couple of seconds you can press any icon and it works, and then the touchpad hangs and after 15 seconds there is a window - "Program memory is very low".

Program memory is very low. You must select one task to close, or increase the amount of program memory, if available.

(*) Convert some Storage Memory to Program Memory. (You can use the System control panel to adjust memory later.)

The touchscreen doesn't work, it's impossible to remove it or press Ok.  Rebooting does nothing, everything is the same again. I connected third-party wired and wireless mice - do not work.

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)[image]